# How to set same color for non unique records in view

Tags: php, algorithm, codeigniter

I'm trying to create if the same data in table row display red color in view.

[image: this is the output in table]

```
<tbody>
<?php 

$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $item) : 

?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
        $text = $item->serial;

        if ($text == $text) {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">' . $text . '</span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="text-success">' . $text . '</span>';
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php 

endforeach;

?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by showing the same data, these will all show red as you compare the value against itself - `$text == $text`.

Comment: I have a problem in my code all result have red color but I want to display is if same data is color red.

Comment: As @NigelRen said, you're comparing a value against itself. That's like checking if 1==1. Which will always be true.

Comment: @JohnMark Can you show the loop code by editing your post?

Comment: @NigelRen bro what is the best way to do that I'm confused this part.

Comment: @JohnMark So you want duplicate values in red?

Comment: @nice_dev yes bro, exampe if have 222,22,22 all of them is red like this but this one is wrong. https://prnt.sc/u1f702

Comment: @nice_dev the different value is default black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep count of serial numbers by looping and set `serial` as key. If key comes again, increment it. When looping to show data, if `serial` count is greater than `1`, it will come in `red`, else it will be black.

**Snippet:**

```
<tbody>
<?php 

$i = 1;

$serial_count = [];

foreach($data as $item):
    $serial_count[$item->serial] = (isset($serial_count[$item->serial]) ? $serial_count[$item->serial] : 0) + 1;
endforeach;

foreach ($data as $item) : 

?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
        $text = $item->serial;

        if ($serial_count[$text] > 1) {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">' . $text . '</span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="text-success">' . $text . '</span>';
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php 

endforeach;

?>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to roll your own counting technique, just isolate the `serial` column of data, then call `array_count_values()`.  Then you have all of the information you need to write a color-styling condition in your markup.

I recommend `printf()` to improve the snippet readability.

Although `text-` is repeated in the class name, I do not like to split the class name to save on characters.  In doing so, when you want to search your project with your IDE for `text-success`, you won't miss this one.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GA0WF))

```
$data = [
    (object)['serial' => 4444, 'note' => '-'],
    (object)['serial' => 4444, 'note' => 'information'],
    (object)['serial' => 111, 'note' => '-'],
];

$serialCounts = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'serial'));

foreach ($data as $obj) {
    printf(
        '<span class="%s">%s</span>',
        $serialCounts[$obj->serial] > 1 ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success',
        $obj->serial
    );
}
```

Output:

```
<span class="text-danger">4444</span>
<span class="text-danger">4444</span>
<span class="text-success">111</span>
```